# Landscape Orientation Left by default (keep right available)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, landscape

I want to launch my application in landscape left per default. But I want to keep the possibility to turn it to landscape right. Is there a way to do so? (Because the app starts in landscape right per default right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is iOS 8+ only, just include the UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft value as the first value in the array for the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations key in your information property list.